# how is an arbitrary dimension "reshaper" turned into a function given a linear index?

Tags: algorithms

i have an arbitrary "reshaping" function which, given a linear sequential array can "reshape" it to 2D or 3D.  the order in which the X-dimension, Y-dimension and Z-dimension may all be changed, as well as the *size* of the X, Y and Z dimensions, may all be changed, *at runtime*.  consequently it is not possible to use static compilers or static allocation.

here is a function that, for the *full* sequential range, prints out a corresponding (remapped) set of indices:

```
(xdim, ydim, zdim) = (3, 2, 5)
lims = [xdim, ydim, zdim]
idxs = [0,0,0]
order = [1,0,2]

for idx in range(xdim * ydim * zdim):
    new_idx = idxs[0] + idxs[1] * xdim + idxs[2] * xdim * ydim
    print new_idx,
    for i in range(3):
        idxs[order[i]] = idxs[order[i]] + 1
        if (idxs[order[i]] != lims[order[i]]):
            break
        print
    idxs[order[i]] = 0
```

what i *actually* need is a function which, when it is passed an arbitrary index, returns *one* (correct) remapped index.

i suppose what i could hypothetically do is have a function that sets up the full array (at startup time), and indexes it.  i would however like to see an algorithmic version of the above.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you, but your question is off-topic here: we deal with computer *science* questions, not programming questions. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Comment: interesting, thanks jack.  i'm probably going to store the full state.  the algorithm itself is unusual: dynamic dimensional reshaping is not something i've seen done before.  it's actually to be used in the design of a 3D GPU, to allow contiguous registers containing arbitrary-arranged matrices to be multiplied and added.

Comment: If you can read the code and translate it to pseudocode, it might become on-topic if you have a specific question about how the algorithm works. By the way, you are supposed to provide a url or reference to the origin of the  "reshaping" function if you want to post your question anywhere.

Comment: http://lists.libre-riscv.org/pipermail/libre-riscv-dev/2018-October/000087.html and http://lists.libre-riscv.org/pipermail/libre-riscv-dev/2018-October/000065.html where there is a reference to an LLVM discussion about Matrices from Vulkan3D  - apologies i appreciate this isn't an "academic" reference!

Answer (score 1):

If the index of $(i,j,k)$ is $p = i + xj + xyk$ then you can compute $i,j,k$ given $p$ as follows:

```
i = p mod x
j = (p / x) mod y
k = (p / x) / y
```

Using this you can solve your problem.

Comment: that makess sense, yuval.  then it becomes possible to treat i j k as an array, and also x y z as an array.  thanks!